# What happens when a value (Object) was removed from Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, garbage-collection

I have questions about what happens to the `Object` when they were removed from `Dictionary`. Lets say I have a following snippet:

```
Dictionary<string, TestClass> classdictionary = new Dictionary<string, TestClass>();

testclass = new TestClass();

classdictionary.Add("1", testclass);

classdictionary.Remove("1");
```

What happens to `testclass` now? Will it be cleaned up  by GC?

Comment: At some time the object might be GC'ed. It might also be that your program exits before the the object is being GC'ed - either some of your code still held a reference to it, or the GC did not have a reason to run so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have another reference to it, it will not be cleaned up.

If your dictionary held the last reference to it, the garbage collector will clean it up. As always, that will not be immediate, but rather some time in the future the GC algorithm feels like doing work.

Comment: Which means if I removed the last line, I can confirm that `testclass` will not be cleaned up, right?

Comment: @TanJiaMing well, if the `classdictionary` gets cleaned up `testClass` would then also get cleaned up next pass of the GC (if there are no other references to `testClass`).

Comment: @TanJiaMing, nope this is not enough to confirm. The dictionary itself could perhaps become eligible for garbage collection, which would also make testclass eligible for garbage collection...